# Underlying thread behavior with Future.get(timeout)

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future, futuretask

We are using `Future` with a timeout to accomplish a task. We get a `TimeOutException` when time limit exceeds. From the behavior of `thread dump`, I realize that underlying thread continues.

Is it the case? How does it take care of multiple threads roaming around? 
What if no `IOException` is thrown for the thread which was removed from the pool?

If this is true, what is the way to `kill` underlying thread. It keeps on waiting for an external `IO` in my case.

A part of thread dump:

```
Thread 29587: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=84, line=129 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=175, line=218 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(byte[], int, int) @bci=44, line=258 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=49, line=317 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=16, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.FilterInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=7, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=4, line=2672 (Compiled frame)
 - javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.readUntil(long) @bci=64, line=121 (Compiled frame)
 - javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=69, line=167 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(long, boolean, boolean) @bci=0 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(boolean) @bci=12, line=532 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly() @bci=92, line=277 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(int) @bci=41, line=409 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(int, boolean) @bci=2, line=525 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(int, javax.imageio.ImageReadParam, boolean) @bci=3, line=968 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(int, javax.imageio.ImageReadParam) @bci=8, line=948 (Compiled frame)
 - javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream) @bci=55, line=1422 (Compiled frame)
 - javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(java.net.URL) @bci=42, line=1374 (Compiled frame)
```

Once TimeOutException occurs (for any task in the loop), we cancel the tasks like this:

```
for(Entry<Requests, Future<?>> futureTask : futureTasks.entrySet())
                {
                    Future<?> future = futureTask.getValue();
                    if(!future.isDone() || future.isCancelled())
                    {
                        future.cancel(true);
                        }
                }
```

Shouldn't it solve the problem?

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the case that your thread continues and executed task is unaffected. *TimeoutException* indicates that you didn't get the result in the appropriate time.

If you want to interrupt underlying thread you can handle the exception and use *cancel(true)* method from the used implementation of *Future*.

**EDIT**

I missed the case that your thread is waiting on a blocking I/O as your stack trace explains. *Thread.interrupt()* which is called from *future.cancel(true)* won't help in this case.

The common pattern in this situtation is to close underlying input stream. I'm not very familiar with *javax.imageio* package but there is an overloaded method on *ImageIO* which accepts the *InputStream*. You might want to store it somewhere and later close it on timeout.

It will call *close()* on *SocketInputStream* which in its turn will call *close()* method of underlying *Socket* which is waiting for blocking read to complete. An executing thread which is blocked in an I/O operation (as per your trace) upon this socket will stop waiting for EOF with *SocketException*.

Comment: Yes, we do that once TimeOutException occurs, I added in the question. Anything else could be the problem?

Comment: @instanceOfObject. Fixed the answer. I guess that stack trace was added after the 1st version of answer or I just didn't pay enough attention - it changed the situation though.